# Why do we need to use collect/collectLatest in different launch blocks?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

```
lifeCycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.oneItem.collect {
        println("one")
    }

    viewModel.twoItem.collectLatest {
        println("two")
    }
}
```

I tried this code, but it only print 'one' and it seems like second collectLatest doesn't work. Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first `collect` function is a `suspend` function, it suspends current coroutine until all items are collected. If `viewModel.oneItem` is infinite then it will never go to the executing of `viewModel.twoItem.collectLatest` function. To invoke both functions in this case two coroutines must be launched:

```
lifeCycleScope.launch {
    launch {
        viewModel.oneItem.collect {
            println("one")
        }
    }
    
    launch {
        viewModel.twoItem.collectLatest {
            println("two")
        }
    }
}
```